# matplotlibのスペクトログラムにyscaleを追加すると何も表示されない

Tags: python, matplotlib

python matplotlibでスペクトログラムのy軸（周波数）を対数表示したいのですが、yscale("log")を追加したところ、なにも表示されなくなりました。
コードは以下のようになります

```
import wave
import struct
from pylab import *

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # WAVEファイルから波形データを取得
    name=sin.wave
    wf = wave.open("ファイル名", "rb")
    data = wf.readframes(wf.getnframes())
    data = frombuffer(data, dtype="int16")
    length = float(wf.getnframes()) / wf.getframerate()  # 波形長さ（秒）

    # FFTのサンプル数
    N = 512
    # FFTで用いるハミング窓
    hammingWindow = np.hamming(N)

    # スペクトログラムを描画
    yscale('log')
    grid(which="both")
    pxx, freqs, bins, im = signal.specgram(data, NFFT=N, Fs=wf.getframerate(), noverlap=120, window=hammingWindow)

    axis([0, 1, 0, 10000])
    yscale("log")
    xlabel("time [second]")
    ylabel("frequency [Hz]")
    show()
```

Comment: `signal.specgram` となっていますが、`scipy.signal` には `specgram()` はありません(`spectrogram()` ならあります。)。仮にこれが `scipy.signal.spectrogram()` だとすると `spectrogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'NFFT'` となってしまいます。`matplotlib.mlab.specgram()` だとすれば(`signal.` を削除)エラーにはなりません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！signal.specgramをspecgramに変えたところうまく通りました！しかし、依然として対数表示はできていないようです... yscale('log')の位置が間違っているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`specgram()` の場合、プロット(というよりは描画)しているのは frequency ではなく、`PSD(Power Spectral Density)`ですので、それを log scale にする必要があります。

具体的には `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor` か `matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh` を使うことになるかと思いますが、`pcolormesh` の方が処理が速いのでそちらを使うことにします。以下、具体的なコードです。

```
pxx, freqs, bins, _ = specgram(data, NFFT=N, Fs=wf.getframerate(),
                               noverlap=120, window=hammingWindow)

pcolormesh(bins, freqs, 10*log10(pxx))

axis([0, 1, 0.01, 10000])
yscale('symlog', linthreshy=0.01)
grid(which='both')
xlabel('time [second]')
ylabel('frequency [Hz]')

show()
```

PSD を `10*log10(pxx)` としていますが、`10*` はあってもなくても構いません(`dB scale` 合わせただけですので)。また、`axis([0, 1, 0.01, 10000])`, `linthreshy=0.01` として frequency の最小値を `0.01` にしていますが、これはデータに合わせて適宜変更して下さい。

参考までにサンプルファイルでの処理結果を載せておきます。

**Log scale**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**Linear scale**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]